# FirebaseAuth multiple Projects with one Emailadress is causing problems although there are no useres

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a problem that has been bothering me for a few days now and for which I cannot find a suitable solution.
I have 3 Firebase projects with my Google Account which currently have no overlap, but they all have the same code (registration and login). All three projects have a FirebaseAuth login option. However, the registration only works for one of my projects, so I've included logs in some places to investigate the cause of the problem. If I run the method below, my Logcat shows me an error message that my email is already being used by another account.
So I deleted all users in all my projects and even allowed the possibility of multiple accounts per email address. The problem still persists.
If I create an account in the Firebase console and then try to log in, Logcat gives the feedback that my user has no password or that the one I have entered is incorrect, this is not the truth of what I can say after several attempts.
I only use EmailAuth.
All the Projects state they are connected and the dependencies are set up correctly. 
Firebase Auth is activated. 
All the projects are running on the Blaze Billing.

What can be the reasons for this strange behavior? or am I just doing something wrong?
Thanks for any help!!

**PART OF MY REGISTRATION WHERE THE PROBLEM OCCOURS**

```
RegistrierungsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (validierung()) {
                    String user_email = Email.getText().toString().trim();
                    String user_password = Password.getText().toString().trim();

                    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user_email,user_password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                sendEmailVerification();
                            } else {
                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                                Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

**LOGCAT (Registration)**

```
 com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException: The email address is already in use by another account.
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdv.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.2.0:5)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzfc.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.2.0:21)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzes.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.2.0:34)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzeu.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.2.0:74)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzeb.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.2.0:18)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zza.onTransact(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.2.0:13)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
```

**LOGCAT (Login)**

```
com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdv.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.2.0:30)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzfc.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.2.0:21)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzes.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.2.0:34)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzeu.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.2.0:74)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzeb.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.2.0:18)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zza.onTransact(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.2.0:13)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
```

Comment: The code looks fine. It really sounds like the app is talking to a different project than the one where (for example) you set to allow multiple accounts per email address.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yeah I thought that too. So I deleted the non-working projects and created new projects using the Firebase Assistant in android studio. The app is connected to this created project. How can the app then talk to another project?